# React DnD Only Works Until the Index Changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I am trying to implement React DnD to change the order of elements rendered from an array (moduleList). For some reason, I can only drag elements until their index changes. After that, they are no longer draggable. For example, if I drag an item with index 0 to between 1 and 2, the first two elements successfully swap places (and indexes), but will no longer respond to drag. I can still grab and drag index item 2, but after I drop it in a new position, it also locks up. Similarly, if I were to start over and drag the item with index 0 to the last position, all items change indexes and and nothing is draggable anymore.

Code (simplified to feature only the relevant bits):

```
const App = ({ modules, status }) => {
    const [moduleList, setModuleList] = useState(modules);

    const dropModule = (input) => {
        const { index, module } = input;
        if (index === null) return;
        let newModules = [...moduleList]
        if (module.key) {
            let toDeleteIndex = moduleList.findIndex(mod => {
                return mod.key === module.key;
            })
            if (toDeleteIndex < 0) return;
            newModules.splice(toDeleteIndex, 1);
            newModules.splice(index, 0, module)
        } else {
            newModules.splice(index, 0, { type: "standard_module", key: Math.random() })
        }
        console.log({newModules})
        setModuleList(newModules)
    }

    const renderModule = (module, index) => {
        const dropRef = useRef(null);
        const dragRef = useRef(null);

        const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop({
            accept: "MODULE",
            drop: () => ({module, index}),
            collect: monitor => ({
                isOver: !!monitor.isOver()
            })
        })

        const [{ isDragging }, drag, dragPreview] = useDrag({
            type: "MODULE",
            item: module,
            end(item, monitor) {
                const dropResult = monitor.getDropResult()
                if (dropResult) dropModule({ module: item, index: dropResult?.index });
            },
            collect: monitor => ({
                isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
            })
        })

        dragPreview(drop(dropRef))
        drag(dragRef)

        return (
            <div ref={dropRef} key={`${index}-${module.key}`}>
                <div ref={dragRef} className="module-menu"><i>expand</i>{index}</div>
                ...module element (code not relevant, I don't think)
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    return (
        <article>
            {
                moduleList.map((module, x) => {
                    return renderModule(module, x)
                })
            }
        </article>
    )

}
```

I don't really understand what is happening, as my code is, as far as I can tell, functionally identical to examples I've found elsewhere. If you think I'm omitting something important, I'll happily update with more detail, but this is all the code relevant to the DnD functionality.

In case it's confusing: the "key" prop on "module" was added because when the key was just a simple index number, React didn't recognize items had swapped positions, and would only render new items to the end of the array. Unique keys helped it recognize the changes I was making. It's probably not the best implementation, but it's the solution that works for now (or DOES it???)

edit: crude CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-sutherland-4l3jxv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Could you reproduce a code sandbox example?

Comment: Done. I didn't make it very pretty, so just know that dragging one item on top of another item will accomplish the drag-n-drop. They use handles, so you have to grab the icon at the left edge of each box, not just anywhere in the box itself.

Comment: For additional reference, this is what I used as a guide. Apart from not using React Table (which I don't need), I do not understand what is critically different between our two projects:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tannerlinsley-react-table-row-dnd-gn4l6?file=/src/App.js